# Can a flat Heegaard splitting surface be totally geodesic?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, geodesic

I'm trying to understand (Meeks, Simon, Yau, 1982), page 652, Corollary of Theorem 5:

> Suppose $N$ is a compact 3-dimensional orientable Riemannian manifold with non-negative Ricci curvature whose boundary, possibly empty, has non-negative mean curvature with respect to the outward normal. If $\Sigma$ is a compact embedded orientable minimal surface in $N$, then one of the following holds:
>
> (1)  $\Sigma$ is a Heegaard surface.
>
> (2) $N$ is flat and  $\Sigma$ is totally geodesic.
>
> (3) $N$ is isometric to $S^2\times S^1$ or $S^2\times I$ with a product metric and $\Sigma$ is one of the sphere factors.
>
> (4) $N$ is diffeomorphic to $P^3$ minus a ball or is diffeomorphic to $P^3\#P^3$ where $P^3$ is a 3D projective space. In this case, $\Sigma$ is a totally geodesic sphere in $N$ such that each component of $N\sim \Sigma$ is isometric to the nontrivial interval bundle over $P^2$ induced as a $Z_2$-quotient of $S^2 \times [0,1]$ with a product metric by an isometry $(x, t)\mapsto (-x, -t)$.

The phrasing makes it sound like the 4 cases are mutually exclusive, and I can understand why, except for cases (1) and (2). I see no reason why a Heegaard surface may not be totally geodesic, or why Heegaard surfaces may not exist in flat space, or why a Heegaard surface can't be flat and totally geodesic at the same time. Still, I'm not sure. So there are two ways I can see case (2) should be interpreted. Either

> $N$ is flat, and $\Sigma$ is totally geodesic and not a Heegaard surface, although it may have been.

or

> $N$ is flat and $\Sigma$ is totally geodesic, so it can't possibly be a Heegaard surface

Which is correct and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the authors do not claim that these cases are mutually exclusive. However, if $N$ is a (closed, oriented, connected) flat 3-d manifold, it cannot have a genus 1 Heegaard decomposition. In particular, it cannot have a flat (e.g. totally geodesic) Heegaard surface. The reason  is quite simple: It follows from Van Kampen's theorem that each genus 1 3-d manifold has cyclic fundamental group (finite or infinite). On the other hand, a compact flat manifold of dimension $>1$ cannot have cyclic fundamental group. This is a nice exercise to work out: if $\gamma$ is an isometry of $E^3$ generating a group $\Gamma$ acting freely, then $\gamma$ preserves a line in $E^3$, hence, the quotient space $E^3/\Gamma$ is a plane bundle over $S^1$, hence, cannot be compact.

At the same time:

1. A Heegaard surface may be totally geodesic (just not in a flat manifold).
2. Heegaard surfaces do exist in every closed connected 3-manifold, even in a flat one. (Just such a surface cannot be flat.)
3. A Heegaard surface can be flat and totally geodesic at the same time: Just not in a flat manifold. For instance, one can find such a surface in $S^3$ equipped with a suitably chosen Riemannian metric.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Sorry if I'm slow, I'm a physicist, not a mathematician. I'll have to do some more reading before I can follow the reasoning, but the points are just what I was looking for. The cases do end up being mutually exclusive, right?  
If you don't mind an extra quick question about case (4) in the corollary: Is there a $P^3$ analogy of $RP^2$ minus a disc being a Möbuis strip, and $RP^2\# RP^2$ being a Klein bottle?

Comment: @PatoRaimundo: Yes, they are mutually exclusive. As for your extra question, I am not even sure what this means. You can say that $RP^3$ minus ball is **a**  nontrivial interval bundle over $RP^2$ (just like Moebius band is **the** nontrivial interval bundle over $RP^1$). The connected sum of two $RP^3$'s is a 2-fold covering over $S^2\times S^1$, so you can regard it as a 3D Klein bottle in this case, but I am unaware of anybody using the name 3D Klein bottle for this connected sum. One can also say that $RP^3\# RP^3$ is **a** nontrivial circle bundle over $RP^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! So it is like the $RP^2$ case, just not uniquely so.